# How to know the tabs selected from vertical and horizontal tabs?

Tags: html, flask, tabs

I have tabs arranged in a HTML page like this :

```
  1 2 3 4 5 
A
B
C
B
D
```

And its like if I select `A and 3`, I can see corresponding data or if I select `D and 1`, I can see whats there.

But I am planning to add a form into it. So if I select `A and 3`,I can see a form.But this tab values are not predefined.It is dynamic and fetched from database. So once form is fetched, How can I know which vertical tab and horizontal tab is pressed? So that I can update the form values to a database to corresponding table.

I am using `python flask` a backend and my code is :

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <div class="vtabs">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-vertical" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#home0" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-home"></i></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">A0</span> </a> </li>
        {% for i in range(1,5) %}
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home{{ i }}" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-home"></i></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">A{{ i }}</span> </a> </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <!-- Tab panes -->
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active show" id="home0" role="tabpanel">
          0
        </div>
        {% for i in range(1,5) %}
        <div class="tab-pane" id="home{{ i }}" role="tabpanel">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body p-b-0">
              <h4 class="card-title">Form header</h4>
              <!-- Nav tabs -->
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs customtab2" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home7" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-home"></i></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">Home</span></a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile7" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-user"></i></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">Profile</span></a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages7" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-email"></i></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">Messages</span></a> </li>
              </ul>
              <!-- Tab panes -->
              <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane" id="home7" role="tabpanel">
                  <div class="p-20">
                    <h5>Best Clean Tab ever</h5>
                    <h6>you can use it with the small code</h6>
                    <p>Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane p-20" id="profile7" role="tabpanel">2</div>
                <div class="tab-pane p-20 active show" id="messages7" role="tabpanel">3</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  < /div>
```

Comment: You can check for the "active" class on the tabs and then pass on the ID of that particular to the backend through AJAX and then load/show/hide the corresponding HTML in the view

Comment: ok let me try this and i will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a hidden field in which you can store the current tab selection. On click of link you can update that hidden field to current selection.

```
<input type="hidden" id="CurrentSelectedTab" />

<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-vertical" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active show" data-toggle="tab" href="#home0" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-home"></i></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">A0</span> </a> </li>
    {% for i in range(1,5) %}
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#home{{ i }}" onclick="return UpdateSeletedTab(i);" role="tab" aria-selected="true">
            <span class="hidden-sm-up"><i class="ti-home"></i></span>
            <span class="hidden-xs-down">A{{ i }}</span>
        </a>

    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateSeletedTab(i) {
        $("#CurrentSelectedTab").value(i);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I have on set of vertical tabs and one set of horizontal tabs. So i have to keep two hidden fields with separate ids right?

Comment: Yes, either you can have two separate fields, or even one can work with some kind of seperator